# Dynamically changing the innerHtml of a Bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, innerhtml

I have the following bootstrap navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand">J+ Iso&epsilon;ditor</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn" id='bts-display-button'></button>
                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="bts-dropdown">

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <button class="btn">New BTS</button>

                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dynamically load `<li>` elements into the `dropdown_menu`. This works fine. I am also trying to change the innerHtml of `bts-display-button` to the value of the clicked `<li>` element.

My CoffeeScript code to achieve this is below:

```
class Toolbar
  constructor: () ->

    @selected_BTS = undefined # The current selected BTS in the BTS dropdown

    @create_toolbar()
    @bts_dropdown_selecion_clickhandler()

  create_toolbar: () =>

  # Add new bts to drop down 
  addBTS: (name) =>
    $('#bts-dropdown').append "<li>#{name}</li>"


  # Set the caption of the bts-dropdown button to what is selected
  bts_dropdown_selecion_clickhandler: () =>
    $('body').on 'click', '#bts-dropdown li', ->
      console.log $(this).html()
      Toolbar.selected_BTS = $(this).html()
      $('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)
```

For example if a user clicks on an element `<li>Hello</li>` in `dropdown_menu` then the console correctly logs the value "Hello" but the innerHtml of `bts-display-button` remains unchanged.

Note: All my scripts are but at the bottom of the html, so that the DOM is ready when the code above is executed.

Please Please could someone help me, as I've been stuck for 2 days on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How many elements with `id` set to `bts-display-button` are there?

Comment: Just the one shown in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing:

$('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)

with

$('body').find('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)

Makes it work.

I have opened a new question disscusing why this might be the case here: [Why does JQuery .find work over just selecting the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043817/why-does-jquery-find-work-over-just-selecting-the-element)