# Why does JQuery .find work over just selecting the element?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, innerhtml

I have been trying to change the innerHtml of a button in Bootstrap by doing the following (CoffeeScript):

```
$('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)
```

This has not been working, even though this is called after the Dom is loaded. I successfully managed to change the innerHtml by using the JQuery .find method as so:

```
$('body').find('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)
```

For some context the above methods are located in a click handler:

```
bts_dropdown_selecion_clickhandler: () =>
    $('body').on 'click', '#bts-dropdown li', ->
      console.log $(this).html()
      Toolbar.selected_BTS = $(this).html()
      $('body').find('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)  # Works
      #$('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS)              # Doesn't Work
```

**Question**

Why does the .find method work but the other doesn't?

Comment: Do you have several elements with the same IDs?

Comment: No, only one element has that id

Comment: Could you show the generated JavaScript for both cases?

Comment: The Generated JavaScript for both cases is identical to the CoffeScript expect for an addition of the semi-colon at the line ends: 

$('body').find('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS);

$('#bts-display-button').html(Toolbar.selected_BTS);

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, no one is going to be able to diagnose this.  `$('body').find('#bts-display-button')` is equivalent to `$('body #bts-display-button')`, which -- assuming your HTML is valid -- is equivalent to `$('#bts-display-button')`. So the problem must lie somewhere in the HTML.